# SQL join total products counted only for one user instead of two that match the ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a simple SQL query to get all users with a certain ID and also count for each user how many products they have. The following SQL statement runs just fine but it only returns one user instead of two. 
It's a simple query which should return both users that match the below id. Any ideas?

```
SELECT UserSocial.user_id, UserSocial.client_id, UserSocial.user_name, UserSocial.user_country, COUNT(product_id) AS total
FROM UserSocial
JOIN Products ON Products.client_id = UserSocial.client_id
WHERE UserSocial.user_id = '100'
```

Comment: Is `user_id` unique?

Comment: @Berkay I have updated my question as it was missing some info. `user_id` is not unique. `UserSocial.client_id` is unique

Comment: What's the expected result for a user without any products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the COUNT(product_id) automatically groups all records into one group because you didn't specify any groups yourself. Try adding a GROUP BY clause like so:

```
SELECT UserSocial.user_id, UserSocial.client_id, UserSocial.user_name, UserSocial.user_country, COUNT(product_id) AS total
FROM UserSocial
JOIN Products ON Products.client_id = UserSocial.client_id
WHERE UserSocial.user_id = '100'
GROUP BY UserSocial.client_id
```

This should make the COUNT function aggregate the product_ids for each user, instead of aggregating the product_ids for all rows in the data set.

Comment: Such a simple solution that I didn't see. Thanks

Comment: Will raise an error in newer MySQL versions. (Unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: do you happen to know what error it will raise or how to prevent it? I'd be happy to fix the answer if I knew the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` to also include users without any products. Add a `GROUP BY`. Use table aliases.

```
SELECT us.user_id, us.client_id, us.user_name, us.user_country, COUNT(product_id) AS total
FROM UserSocial us
LEFT JOIN Products P ON p.client_id = us.client_id
WHERE us.user_id = '100'
GROUP BY us.user_id, us.client_id, us.user_name, us.user_country
```